# No link to tag wiki page found in mobile browser view of tag

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, tag-wiki

In the "Request Desktop Site" view of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86 there is a link titled "Learn more…" that links to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

On the same page in the default (mobile) view there is no link to the tag-wiki apparent to me.

This is on Mozilla Firefox 68.2.1 on Android 9.